# Multiple updates to same table via stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I am having recurring deadlocks on my application database and trying to understand what is causing them. Using extended events to track them I have identified two common causes, one via an T-SQL statement in the application and the other using a stored procedure. I'll limit this question just to the stored procedure.

I have a stored procedure called writeNominalTrans, I pass some variables from the software and it will either insert or update a record depending on whether a match is found. The XML Deadlock reports commonly refer to the update statements causing the problems, I'll post both stored procedure and an example XML report below.
I have done some reading to understand Deadlocks but most sources just talk about locking between two tables where as my issues resolve around updating records in a single table and not sure exactly how to resolve this.

I think this issue is that it locks the table by pages, possibly multiple at a time as it searches, looking for the correct row to update. If multiple users call the same procedure at the same time, it causes different pages to be locked, ending up with both waiting on each other to finish and thus a Deadlock. Please correct me if this isnt the case.
Within the stored procedure, there are begin/end statements with multiple update statements and not sure if this is one of the potentially issues. Should I put each update statement within it's own begin/end so it is only trying to do one statement at a time? This is assuming it is firing multiple statements per user and some times there are a larger number of processes than in the example below. Aside from this I'm not sure what else is causing the problem, please if you take a look and lend me your expertise.
Regards
David

Stored Procedure

```
[dbo].[spWriteNominalTrans]
@Recordkey Int Output,
@NominalDataKey int, 
@NominalCode int, 
@NominalType int, 
@TransDate datetime, 
@Memo  nvarchar(500),
@debit money,
@Credit money,
@VatValueIN money,
@VatValueOut money,
@VatNLAccount int, 
@VatRelationKey int, 
@Reference nvarchar(50),
@Period int,
@FiscalYear int,
@UserID int,
@DateStamp datetime,
@Transtype nvarchar(150),
@vatcode int,
@vatrate decimal(18,2),
@GoodsValue money,
@AllowMerge bit,
@VatReconcileKey Integer,
@VatOut bit,
@LocationKey int
AS

IF exists ( select * from TblNominalTrans where TransDate= @TransDate and NominalCode = @NominalCode and Period = @Period and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear and Reference = @Reference and vatcode = @vatcode and transtype = @Transtype and @AllowMerge=1 and Memo=@Memo and @Transtype=Transtype and LocationKey =@LocationKey)
-- do an update
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TblNominalTrans SET
        Memo=@Memo,
        Debit = Debit + @Debit ,
        Credit = Credit +@Credit,
        GoodsValue = GoodsValue + @GoodsValue,
        VatValueIN = VatValueIN + @VatValueIN,
        VatValueOut = VatValueOut + @VatValueOut,
        VatOut = @Vatout,
        VatNLAccount=@VatNLAccount,
        VatRelationKey=@VatRelationKey,
        UserId=@UserId,
        DateStamp=@DateStamp,
        VatReconcileKey = @VatReconcileKey
        WHERE TransDate= @TransDate and NominalCode = @NominalCode and Period = @Period and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear and Reference = @Reference  and vatcode = @vatcode and Memo=@Memo and @Transtype=Transtype and LocationKey = @LocationKey

        UPDATE TblNominalTrans SET
        Credit = Credit - Debit, debit = 0
        WHERE TransDate= @TransDate and NominalCode = @NominalCode and Period = @Period and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear and Reference = @Reference  and vatcode = @vatcode and Memo=@Memo and @Transtype=Transtype and LocationKey = @LocationKey and credit >= debit and debit > 0
         
        UPDATE TblNominalTrans SET
        Debit = Debit - Credit, credit = 0
        WHERE TransDate= @TransDate and NominalCode = @NominalCode and Period = @Period and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear and Reference = @Reference  and vatcode = @vatcode and Memo=@Memo and @Transtype=Transtype and LocationKey = @LocationKey and debit >= credit and credit > 0        
    END
ELSE
-- do an insert
    BEGIN
        INSERT TblNominalTrans (
        NominalDataKey,
        NominalCode,
        NominalType , 
        TransDate , 
        Memo ,
        debit ,
        Credit ,
        VatValueIN,
        VatValueOut ,
        VatNLAccount , 
        VatRelationKey , 
        Reference ,
        Period ,
        FiscalYear , 
        VatOut ,
        TransType , 
        UserID ,
        DateStamp,
        vatcode,
        vatrate,
        Goodsvalue,
        VatReconcileKey,
        LocationKey)
        SELECT
        @NominalDataKey , 
        @NominalCode , 
        @NominalType , 
        @TransDate , 
        @Memo ,
        @debit ,
        @Credit ,
        @VatValueIN,
        @VatValueOut ,
        @VatNLAccount , 
        @VatRelationKey , 
        @Reference ,
        @Period,
        @FiscalYear,
        @VatOut,
        @transtype,
        @UserID,
        @DateStamp,
        @vatcode,
        @vatrate,
        @goodsvalue,
        @VatReconcileKey,
        @LocationKey
    END
```

Deadlock XML Report

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process2c457dd0ca8" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process2c457dd0ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:23277 " waittime="1684" ownerId="1782665" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2022-12-13T09:46:09" XDES="0x2c314a19900" lockMode="U" schedulerid="3" kpid="3212" status="suspended" spid="66" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2022-12-13T09:46:08.930" lastbatchcompleted="2022-12-13T09:46:08.923" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.923" clientapp="Liquidity" hostname="TERM-SERVER" hostpid="5228" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1782665" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="536870944" clientoption2="128024">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="MDT_DB.dbo.spWriteNominalTrans" line="43" stmtstart="2092" stmtend="3384" sqlhandle="0x030007002b291964daa21d01caac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE TblNominalTrans
         SET
         Memo=@Memo,
         Debit = Debit + @Debit ,
         Credit = Credit +@Credit,
         GoodsValue = GoodsValue + @GoodsValue,
         VatValueIN = VatValueIN + @VatValueIN,
         VatValueOut = VatValueOut + @VatValueOut,
         VatOut = @Vatout,
         VatNLAccount=@VatNLAccount,
         VatRelationKey=@VatRelationKey,
         UserId=@UserId,
         DateStamp=@DateStamp,
         VatReconcileKey = @VatReconcileKey
         WHERE TransDate= @TransDate and NominalCode = @NominalCode and Period = @Period and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear and Reference = @Reference  and vatcode = @vatcode and Memo=@Memo and @Transtype=Transtype and LocationKey = @LocationKe    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1679370539]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process2c457d96108" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:2425 " waittime="1686" ownerId="1782668" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2022-12-13T09:46:09.003" XDES="0x2c45d69d900" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="3336" status="suspended" spid="176" sbid="0" ecid="1" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2022-12-13T09:46:08.817" lastbatchcompleted="2022-12-13T09:46:08.813" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.813" clientapp="Liquidity" hostname="DESKTOP-O2" hostpid="8728" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1782668" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="536870944" clientoption2="128024">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="MDT_DB.dbo.spWriteNominalTrans" line="64" stmtstart="4210" stmtend="4886" sqlhandle="0x030007002b291964daa21d01caac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE TblNominalTrans
         SET
         Debit = Debit - Credit, credit = 0
         WHERE TransDate= @TransDate and NominalCode = @NominalCode and Period = @Period and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear and Reference = @Reference  and vatcode = @vatcode and Memo=@Memo and @Transtype=Transtype and LocationKey = @LocationKey and debit &gt;= credit and credit &gt;    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1679370539]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process2c457d97468" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:23277 " waittime="1686" ownerId="1782665" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2022-12-13T09:46:09" XDES="0x2c3ab371cb0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="5808" status="suspended" spid="66" sbid="0" ecid="1" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2022-12-13T09:46:08.930" lastbatchcompleted="2022-12-13T09:46:08.923" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.923" clientapp="Liquidity" hostname="TERM-SERVER" hostpid="5228" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1782665" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="536870944" clientoption2="128024">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="MDT_DB.dbo.spWriteNominalTrans" line="43" stmtstart="2092" stmtend="3384" sqlhandle="0x030007002b291964daa21d01caac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE TblNominalTrans
         SET
         Memo=@Memo,
         Debit = Debit + @Debit ,
         Credit = Credit +@Credit,
         GoodsValue = GoodsValue + @GoodsValue,
         VatValueIN = VatValueIN + @VatValueIN,
         VatValueOut = VatValueOut + @VatValueOut,
         VatOut = @Vatout,
         VatNLAccount=@VatNLAccount,
         VatRelationKey=@VatRelationKey,
         UserId=@UserId,
         DateStamp=@DateStamp,
         VatReconcileKey = @VatReconcileKey
         WHERE TransDate= @TransDate and NominalCode = @NominalCode and Period = @Period and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear and Reference = @Reference  and vatcode = @vatcode and Memo=@Memo and @Transtype=Transtype and LocationKey = @LocationKe    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1679370539]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process2c45d6984e8" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="1624" schedulerid="4" kpid="5024" status="suspended" spid="176" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-12-13T09:46:08.817" lastbatchcompleted="2022-12-13T09:46:08.813" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.813" clientapp="Liquidity" hostname="DESKTOP-O2" hostpid="8728" loginname="LOCAL\debbie.weavers" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1782668" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="536870944" clientoption2="128024">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="MDT_DB.dbo.spWriteNominalTrans" line="64" stmtstart="4210" stmtend="4886" sqlhandle="0x030007002b291964daa21d01caac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE TblNominalTrans
         SET
         Debit = Debit - Credit, credit = 0
         WHERE TransDate= @TransDate and NominalCode = @NominalCode and Period = @Period and FiscalYear = @FiscalYear and Reference = @Reference  and vatcode = @vatcode and Memo=@Memo and @Transtype=Transtype and LocationKey = @LocationKey and debit &gt;= credit and credit &gt;    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1679370539]   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="23277" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="MDT_DB.dbo.tblNominalTrans" id="lock2c3c82bb300" mode="U" associatedObjectId="287811838279680">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process2c457d97468" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process2c457dd0ca8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="2425" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="MDT_DB.dbo.tblNominalTrans" id="lock2c431d37300" mode="U" associatedObjectId="287811838279680">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process2c457dd0ca8" mode="U" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process2c457d96108" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="23277" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="MDT_DB.dbo.tblNominalTrans" id="lock2c3c82bb300" mode="U" associatedObjectId="287811838279680">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process2c45d6984e8" mode="U" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process2c457d97468" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
  <exchangeEvent id="Pipe2c3488ae780" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" nodeId="4">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process2c457d96108" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process2c45d6984e8" />
   </waiter-list>
  </exchangeEvent>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: That `SELECT` along with the multiple UPDATE/INSERTs guarantee a deadlock. Both connections take `S`hared locks with `SELECT` then both try to upgrade them to e`X`clusive with UPDATE or INSERT. That fails because the *other* connection has also taken a Shared lock. You can use a `FROM` clause with both INSERT and UPDATE and get rid of the extra SELECT

Comment: The deadlock reports never mention the select statement, only the updates and all with "U" locks which is why I discounted it. However I have read that using * is a bad idea and can probably change it to the record key. The stored procedure wasnt initially created by me but is structured similar to others where a select statement is used to determine if a record exists in order to work out if INSERT or Update is needed and these dont have the issue, as yet. How would I get rid of it and use a From clause instead?